# insertFileFromBase64 sometimes creates a blank page at the start of the document

Tags: ms-word, office-js

When inserting a file, sometimes it is inserted with an extra leading page in the document.

I'm using this code:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
    var body = context.document.body;
    body.clear();
    body.insertFileFromBase64(base64String, Word.InsertLocation.replace);

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        console.log('Added base64 encoded text to the beginning of the document body.');
    });
});
```

Sometimes it is fine. If you decode the to a file using https://www.base64decode.org/ and rename the resulting file to `something.docx`, the string is one page and starts from the top of that page. But if you load the same string through `insertFileFromBase64` as above, there is a leading blank page.

For file examples please refer to this [Github issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/1266).